# What is the correct syntax for DELETE TOP statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, delete-row

I want do delete only 1 row of the table "trader_inventory" where the "item_id" is 14 and "trader_id" is 1.
This is the code I've tried:

```
DELETE TOP 1 
FROM trader_inventory 
WHERE item_id = 14 AND trader_id = 1;
```

I also tried this to see if its only working with 1 condition:

```
DELETE TOP 1
FROM trader_inventory
WHERE item_id = 14;
```

I also tried with brackets at "TOP (1)"

SQL says Syntax-error at '1 FROM trader_inventory WHERE item_id = 14'

I can't explain why it's not working. I am trying to find a solution for 2 hours now. I hope someone can help me.
I saw that some people write their table names in []-brackets but that didn't work for me. SQL marked it as wrong.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: How do I tag my question? Sorry this is my very first question on stackoverflow.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you would use:

```
DELETE FROM trader_inventory
    WHERE item_id = 14 AND trader_id = 1
    LIMIT 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5ca1d1ae039c3d6e69999f252bb67696) is a db<>fiddle.

There is no `SELECT TOP` in MySQL.  If you were using SQL Server (as suggested by the use of `TOP`), you can use a subquery (or CTE):

```
DELETE ti
    FROM (SELECT TOP (1) ti.*
          FROM trader_inventory ti
          WHERE item_id = 14 AND trader_id = 1
         ) ti;
```

Note:  `SELECT TOP` is usually used with an `ORDER BY` so the results are consistent.  This deletes an arbitrary row.  And if you run it on a table with the same rows, different rows could be chosen.

Comment: I did copy&paste your code and now it says syntax-error at '.*
          FROM trader_inventory
          WHERE item_id = 14 AND trader_inv...'

what does "ti" stand for?

Comment: @RobinFlickinger . . . Added the missing table alias.

Comment: @RobinFlickinger . . . Amusing.  I just learned that the `FROM` clause is not allowed with `LIMIT`.  I thought it was the `JOIN` that triggered the multi-table syntax.